# Annul event in another javascript document

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two documents in javascript I have an access to other non, i do not want the click event one.js in this work, only my two.js.

```
    one.js // I dont have acess

    $(document).ready(function(e){
       $('.contentsummary .actions a').click(function(e){
          $('.contentsummary .items').css('top','2000px');
       );
    });


   two.js // My File JS

  $(document).ready(function(e){
       $('.contentsummary .actions a').click(function(e){
          $('.contentsummary .items').css('top','0');
       );
   });
```

Comment: Why are you loading `one.js` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the event listener prior to adding yours:

```
   $(document).ready(function(e){
       $('.contentsummary .actions a').off('click');
       $('.contentsummary .actions a').on('click', function(e){
          $('.contentsummary .items').css('top','0');
       );
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.7 onwards the `.click()` method internally uses [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to bind the event handler

Hence you can use [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off) to remove the existing handler:

> The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $('.contentsummary .actions a').off('click').on('click', function(e){
      $('.contentsummary .items').css('top','0');
   );
});
```

---

Prior jQuery 1.7, Use [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind):

> Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind().

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $('.contentsummary .actions a').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e){
      $('.contentsummary .items').css('top','0');
   );
});
```

---

Side note: Make sure your script runs after the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind the click handler before adding another click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   $('.contentsummary .actions a').off('click').on('click',function(e){
      $('.contentsummary .items').css('top','0');
   );
});
```

Example for the off and on methods: http://jsfiddle.net/8c6po6ft/
Related question: [How to overwrite jquery event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741628/how-to-overwrite-jquery-event-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

While others suggested how to fix the issues brought by a design issue, I suggest that you should rather fix your design issue.

If there's code that shouldn't run, why do you actually run that code? If in your new page you only need `two.js` and a subset of `one.js` excluding some pieces of it, well you should further segregated your code into more files.

```
subset-of-one.js
two.js
```

Having many files with `$.ready` is also another bad practice, but that's probably outside the scope of this question.