# YouTube API nextPageToken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm fairly new to javascript and I'm kinda stuck in using the youTube API. I'm able to get results with the data I need, loop through each of them and display them, but the problem is with the nextPageToken. I can't seem to figure out why after the second search function with the nextPage token, I'm unable to discard the old one thus, I'm getting multiple, duplicate results.

I'm logging the tokens to see and track them and I always get the previous token duplicated

```
<body>

 <div class="youtube-feed container">
  <script id="template" type=test/template>
    <div class="youtube-item">
        <a href="{{link}}" class="link">
            <img src="{{thumb}}" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="info">
            <h6 class="title">{{title}}</h6>
            <p>{{channel}}</p>
            <p>{{views}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>

<div class="button container">
 <a href="#" id="next">Next Page</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 (function() {
    var query = 'Random search string',
        apiKey = 'api key here';

    getData();

    function getData() {
        $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: query,
            type: 'video',
            maxResults: 10,
            key: apiKey},
        function(data) {
            var nextToken = data.nextPageToken;
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                var resultsData = {
                    id: item.id.videoId,
                    title: item.snippet.title,
                    desc: item.snippet.description,
                    thumb: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url,
                    channel: item.snippet.channelTitle
                };

                $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', {
                    part: 'statistics',
                    id: resultsData.id,
                    key: apiKey},
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                        var views = item.statistics.viewCount;
                            resultsData.viewCount = views;
                    });
                    renderData(resultsData);
                });
            });
            nextButton(nextToken);
        });
    };

    function renderData(obj) {
        var template = $.trim($('#template').html()),
            dataVals = template.replace(/{{id}}/ig, obj.id)
                                .replace(/{{title}}/ig, obj.title)
                                .replace(/{{thumb}}/ig, obj.thumb)
                                .replace(/{{channel}}/ig, obj.channel)
                                .replace(/{{views}}/ig, obj.viewCount)
                                .replace(/{{link}}/ig, 'https://www.youtube/com/embed/' + obj.id);
        $(dataVals).appendTo('.youtube-feed');
    };

    function nextButton(token) {
        $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            nextPage(token);
        });
    };

    function nextPage(token) {
        $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: query,
            type: 'video',
            maxResults: 2,
            pageToken: token,
            key: apiKey},
        function(data) {
            var nextToken = data.nextPageToken;
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                var resultsData = {
                    id: item.id.videoId,
                    title: item.snippet.title,
                    desc: item.snippet.description,
                    thumb: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url,
                    channel: item.snippet.channelTitle
                };

                $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', {
                    part: 'statistics',
                    id: resultsData.id,
                    key: apiKey},
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                        var views = item.statistics.viewCount;
                        resultsData.viewCount = views;
                    });
                    renderData(resultsData);
                });
            });
            nextButton(nextToken);
            console.log(nextToken);
        });
    };
 })();
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove your click event handler before adding a new one otherwise they will add up, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741628/how-to-overwrite-jquery-event-handlers) :

```
$('#next').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nextPage(token);
});
```

Here is a complete example which also deals with the last page (when there is no `pageToken` field) :

```html
<body>

  <div class="youtube-feed container">
    <script id="template" type=test/template>
      <div class="youtube-item">
        <a href="{{link}}" class="link">
          <img src="{{thumb}}" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="info">
          <h6 class="title">{{title}}</h6>
          <p>{{channel}}</p>
          <p>{{views}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
  </div>

  <div class="button container">
    <a href="#" id="next">Next Page</a>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function() {
      var query = 'TANNOY dvs 6',
        apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

      var reachLastPage = false;

      getData();

      function getData() {
        $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: query,
            type: 'video',
            maxResults: 10,
            key: apiKey
          },
          function(data) {

            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
              var resultsData = {
                id: item.id.videoId,
                title: item.snippet.title,
                desc: item.snippet.description,
                thumb: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url,
                channel: item.snippet.channelTitle
              };

              $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', {
                  part: 'statistics',
                  id: resultsData.id,
                  key: apiKey
                },
                function(data) {
                  $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                    var views = item.statistics.viewCount;
                    resultsData.viewCount = views;
                  });
                  renderData(resultsData);
                });
            });

            if (data.nextPageToken) {
              console.log("go to token : " + data.nextPageToken);
              nextButton(data.nextPageToken);
            } else {
              console.log("no page left");
              reachLastPage = true;
            }
          });
      };

      function renderData(obj) {
        var template = $.trim($('#template').html()),
          dataVals = template.replace(/{{id}}/ig, obj.id)
          .replace(/{{title}}/ig, obj.title)
          .replace(/{{thumb}}/ig, obj.thumb)
          .replace(/{{channel}}/ig, obj.channel)
          .replace(/{{views}}/ig, obj.viewCount)
          .replace(/{{link}}/ig, 'https://www.youtube/com/embed/' + obj.id);
        $(dataVals).appendTo('.youtube-feed');
      };

      function nextButton(token) {
        $('#next').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (!reachLastPage) {
            nextPage(token);
          } else {
            console.log("we already have reached last page!");
          }
        });
      };

      function nextPage(token) {
        $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
            part: 'snippet, id',
            q: query,
            type: 'video',
            maxResults: 2,
            pageToken: token,
            key: apiKey
          },
          function(data) {

            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
              var resultsData = {
                id: item.id.videoId,
                title: item.snippet.title,
                desc: item.snippet.description,
                thumb: item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url,
                channel: item.snippet.channelTitle
              };

              $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', {
                  part: 'statistics',
                  id: resultsData.id,
                  key: apiKey
                },
                function(data) {
                  $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                    var views = item.statistics.viewCount;
                    resultsData.viewCount = views;
                  });
                  renderData(resultsData);
                });
            });
            if (data.nextPageToken) {
              console.log("go to token : " + data.nextPageToken);
              nextButton(data.nextPageToken);
            } else {
              console.log("no page left");
              reachLastPage = true;
            }
          });
      };
    })();
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: The .off() method was the solution, which I was unaware of before. Thanks! It's now working.