# jQuery preventing postback on button click

Tags: jquery

How can I attach a click event to a button and prevent postback?

The code I have doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('#btnNext').click(function() {
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: <STRIKE>See this: [How to remove an event handler](http://jquery.open2space.com/node/23)</STRIKE> And This: [best way to remove an event handler in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Comment: Good question but lacking a comparative example.  Since web developers today, use a blended approach, it is always good to provide an example of the HTML control not just assume the type of the selector.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
$('#btnNext').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I've noticed that this doesn't work either due to asp.net rendering. My button gets rendered with a "javascript:__doPostBack(". Any ideas on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Change the `$('#btnNext')` to this:  `$('#<%=btnNext.ClientID%>')`.  By default, ASP.Net uses their own ID naming... so by using the ClientID property, you can get the actual name to reference.

Comment: Adding to User434917's answer: Encosia has a good writeup on this [here](http://encosia.com/button-click-handlers-ajax-premature-submission/) - (Button click handlers, AJAX, and premature submission)

Comment: @VincePanuccio you can't get rid of that, since it is what allows non-Submit controls to perform PostBack behavior.  Either ignore it or understand it and utilize it to perform PostBack's from the Client-Side.

Answer (score 21):

I was working with a button and discovered that if you want to prevent the button from doing an auto-postback, you need to specify the type as "button".  For example:

```
<button id="saveButton">Save</button>
```

--this will generate an auto-postback (tested in IE)

```
<button type="button" id="saveButton">Save</button>
```

--this will not

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Elegant, simple, and requires no js whatsoever. Not only did this solve my problem, but did so in a way that didn't bloat my codebase. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeWerner problem is that some developers use the ASP controls instead of raw HTML.  Some developers are lazy, i know.  Either way this only works for those that use Raw HTML to build a webpage.

Answer (score 4):

**In Asp.net to prevent page postback on button click use preventDefault() function**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>WebForm1</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnshow").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#Label1").show();
                });
                $("#btnhide").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#Label1").hide();
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

        </div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnshow" runat="server" Text="Show" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnhide" runat="server" Text="Hide" />
        </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is probably the best practical approach, as it pertains directly to the .Net quandary.  In some scenario's, you should also handle dynamic control ID assignment, pending on the environment.

Comment: How does this differ from [the answer posted 7 years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/887938/215552)?

Answer (score -1):

inside button tag, use type="Button" to prevent from post back.

Comment: Same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23957909/215552) posted in May of the same year.