# How to trim text inside textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea, I would like to trim the text inside it and display the result.

Example:

> " 1234 "

becomes

> "1234"

However for some reason it doesn't trim the text, and it returns nothing.

HTML

```
<form id="form1">
 <textarea id="text-area" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="text here..."></textarea><br>        
 <button class="button" onclick="myFunc()">Sumbit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
function myFunc(){

    var getText = document.getElementById("text-area").textContent;
    var result = getText;

    result.trim();

    document.getElementById("text-area").textContent = result;
}
```

No JQuery please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery preventing postback on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887923/jquery-preventing-postback-on-button-click)

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's a different problem.

Comment: Two problems; 1. clicking a button inside a form will submit the form by default. 2. `result.trim()` returns the result of the trim operation, so you'll need to set `textContent` to the result.

Comment: @Barmar But certainly part of it, because even if you fix the problem of throwing away the `trim()` result, it's not going to stick around...

Comment: @HereticMonkey It doesn't need to stick around, the corrected input gets submitted in the form.

Comment: @Barmar Assuming that's what the OP wants; "...and it returns nothing".

Answer (score 2):

It is failing because, `.trim`does not mutates the actual string. It returns a new string. All you need to do is `result = result.trim();`

```js
function myFunc(){
    var result = document.getElementById("text-area").value;
    console.log(result);
    result = result.trim();
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById("text-area").value = result
}
```

```html
  <textarea id="text-area" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="text here..."></textarea>
  <br>        
  <button class="button" onclick="myFunc()">Sumbit</button>
```

Comment: this doesn't actually trim the text. Did you run your snippet?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have updated my answer. But my point was not how to read and set value in text area. I wanted to explain how `.trim` works. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @ADyson please remove the -ve score. If you think, I have resolved the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. P.S. the original question said " I would like to trim the text inside it and display the result.", so to answer it fully you really have to implement all of that I think. Now your code does that, so have an upvote. I think our answers are pretty similar now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `value` property, not `textContent`. And `trim()` returns a new string rather than modifying the old one. Also you can make the code much more concise.

Demo:

```js
function myFunc() {
  var ta = document.getElementById("text-area");
  ta.value = ta.value.trim();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text-area" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="text here..."></textarea><br>
<button class="button" onclick="myFunc()">Submit</button>
```

(Note: I removed the form tags so it won't submit the form, and so you can see the result of the trim operation when you press Submit. I also corrected the typo - `Sumbit` should be `Submit`.

Answer (score 0):

`result.trim()` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the existing one.

```js
    document.getElementById("text-area").textContent = result.trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
function myFunc(){

    var getText = document.getElementById("text-area").textContent;
    document.getElementById("text-area").textContent = getText.trim();
}
```

trim method doesn't affect the string it was called on. It returns the trimmed string.