# How many ways are there to remove/destroy an event handler in jquery?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I'm looking through a plugin that somebody else has written and for some reason all my click event handlers are destroyed.  I'm going through the code and there are several uses of unbind which I've commented out to determine whether it is causing the issue.  Unfortunately that is not enough, so I'm wondering if there are other ways to remove/destroy event handlers?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Comment: Thanks for the link... maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the above refer to the use to unbind? I've commented out all instances of unbind and still no luck.

Comment: is there a stopPropagation(); (or return false;) that is preventing it from getting to your handlers?

Comment: unfortunately no stopPropagtion... some uses of return false but they don't appear to be interfering.

Answer (score 0):

There is `.unbind()` which will unbind a collection's event once, or `.die()` which is the opposite of `.live()`, meaning it will unbind the collection's event that is currently set, and any events that are attached in the future.

Comment: Are you doing any DOM manipulation for the elements with .click() events?  If you use .remove(), then event handlers aren't saved.  If you use .detach(), then you need to make sure you are caching the removed elements.

Comment: I'm not doing any direct DOM manipulation in my own code, however when I execute $($.plugin).remove() that is when my click events are being removed.