# Javascript - Cancel onload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onload

```
    var town_imgs = $('.town_img img');
    var container;
    var imggg
    town_imgs.hover(function(){

        container = $('<div class="town_img_thmb">'
                +'<span class="thmb_container ajax2"></span>'
            +'</div>').appendTo($(this).parents('.town_wrapper').find('.thmb_wrapper'));

        var imggg = new Image(140,100);             
        imggg.onload = function(){
            container.find('.thmb_container').append(this);
        }
        imggg.src = $(this).attr('src').replace(/\/t0\//,'/t1/');               

    },function(){

        container.remove();
        $(imggg).unbind('onload');

    });
```

Isn't working when I'm hovering thumbnails very fast. It displays 2-3 images in a row for a about 250-500ms~

As I understand it happens because I'm using outside variable to store current thumbnail.

Is it?

Is there solution to cancel onload event properly?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Found the problem. Used imggg.onload = null instead of unbind.

Comment: You should look at using hoverIntent http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html which builds in a delay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 problems, you want to remove `var` from this, so your reference is correct:

```
var imggg = new Image(140,100);
```

Then unbind by clearing the `onload` function you set:

```
imggg.onload = null;
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gjH6E/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Cancel/destroy **`onload`** event using **`jQuery`**

You can use **`unbind`** function.

```
$('#myimage').unbind('click');
```

You can get more help from here:
[Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)