# jquery: live() or bind() does not work after using load() and return false within it

Tags: load, bind, jquery

following up on this thread [jquery: live() - only lives once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093361/jquery-live-only-lives-once) I found out what the problem is in my code whether I use live() or bind() - I have this line below after using load(),

```
$('.disabled').click(function(){return false;});
```

If I don't use this line the page will 'return' the link in the a tag if I click on the button again. for instance, this is the first button (a text link button) -

```
<a href="another_page.php">button 1 </a>
```

what have I done wrong by adding that line? any idea how I can resolve this...?

below is some more code of this function I am trying to resolve this problem,

```
$('.load-item-news:not(.disabled)').bind('click',function(){

        ...

        /* add a .current class to the target item */
        $(this).parentsUntil('.column-global').addClass('current');

        /* add .disabled class to each a tag in the .current element-div */
        $('.current a').addClass('disabled');

        ...

        /* prepend a fresh div */
        $('.column-global.right').prepend('<div class="wrapper-item"></div>');

        ...

        var path = $(this).attr('href');
        var item_wrapper = $('.wrapper-item');

        var array_path = path.split('/');
        var pg_url = $(array_path).last()[0];

        item_wrapper.load(http_root+rp_template+'item_content_news.php?pg_urlx='+pg_url, function(){

            ...

            $('.disabled').click(function(){return false;});
            //$('.current a').click(function(){return false;});

        });

        return false;
    });
```

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue.  First, I always recommend normalizing the behavior of buttons across browsers by doing $('button').live('click', function() { return false; });  This is bound to the document level and is always fired last due to event bubbling.  If you could provide some more detail I'd be glad to help.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply and the help. I got it fixed now with the suggestion from T.J. Crowder's answer below. thanks so much! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$('.disabled').click(function(){return false;});
```

...you do two things by returning `false`:

1. You prevent the browser default (like [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)), and
2. You prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM (like [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)).

If you only want to do one or the other (like just preventing the default), you can do that:

```
$('.disabled').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); });
```

That way you're preventing the default action but not stopping bubbling, and so any `live` handler you have should eventually be triggered.

But I wonder if you really want to be doing this. I'm guessing if a link can have the class "disabled", that it can be "enabled" sometimes? Just removing the "disabled" class won't turn off that click handler (that's part of what `live` is for, handling changes for you). For instance:

```
$('.disabled').live('click', function(event){ event.preventDefault(); });
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- Note the change
```

...tells jQuery that rather than looking for elements that have the class "disabled" *now*, you want it to check when the click occurs and only run the handler if the element matches at *that* point in time.

Comment: thanks for the reply and the explaination. now I know what I have done wrong. the code runs perfectly now! thanks so much! :-)

Comment: Live binds handlers to the document, so return false should be okay.  Since there is nothing to bubble past the document.  One caveat, any other handlers bound at the document level won't fire for that event.  [Actually I think I couldnt be right/wrong, since browsers may fire events in different orders]

Comment: @John: Yeah, good point although I think jQuery does some emulation within `live`. Re event handler order, if you hook up all of your handlers via jQuery, it guarantees the order regardless of browser (always fires in order they were hooked up). Handlers bound to actual elements fire before those bound with `live` or `delegate` (of course); I don't know whether they guarantee what happens if multiple `live` handlers handle to the same element, don't immediately see it in the docs, but I suspect it's the same (order of `live` calls). :-)