# disable onclick event jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following code

http://www.jsfiddle.net/uZc8w/

what i'm simply wondering is how would i with jquery/javascript remove that attr so it wouldnt work anymore

Comment: use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery) may be its hepful for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

Updated [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/uZc8w/1/)

Comment: how come unbind or the solution i posted there doesn't work but removeAttr does ?

Comment: because jquery did not attach the event so it cannot unbind it.

Comment: @Breezer: and instead of bin/unbind use on/off. For With jQuery 1.7 onward the event API has been updated, .bind()/.unbind() are still available for backwards compatibility, but the preferred method is using the on()/off() functions.