# How to prevent events from raising?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is it possible that if one event raise prevent others from raising?

**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c52Wr/)**

```
$(window).click(
    function(e)
    {
        $("#out").html("preventing next event from happening\n");
    });

$(window).click(
    function(e)
    {
        $("#out").html($("#out").html() + "evil event should not write here");
    });
```

Comment: The order of the events doesn't matter. It matters that if one execute the others don't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(window).click(
    function(e)
    {
        $("#out").html("preventing next event from happening\n");
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

$(window).click(
    function(e)
    {
        $("#out").html($("#out").html() + "evil event should not write here");
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/ -- read more here

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use preventDefault() to stop the other event from occurring. This may be overkill for your solution, however, because it doesn't really give you a choice in which event fires.

http://jsfiddle.net/c52Wr/1/

```
$(window).click(
    function(e)
    {
        $("#out").html("preventing next event from happening\n");
        e.preventdefault();
    });

$(window).click(
    function(e)
    {
        $("#out").html($("#out").html() + "evil event should not write here");
    });
```

A better solution may be to accept a click and some parameter and check that parameter to decide how you want to respond.