# How to disable prettyPhoto?

Tags: javascript, prettyphoto, disabled-control

I now how to enable prettyphoto, but the problem is how to disable?

Here i enable prettyPhoto

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({ social_tools:false, }); });
```

**How to disable?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").unbind('click');
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").attr('rel', '');
```

Just unbind click and rel attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the prettyPhoto does not seem to have a "turnOff" option.
If you are not using any other click event handlers for those links, @Yenne Info 's answer is just fine.

**If you don't want to unbind all click event handlers:**

Looking through the prettyPhoto code - at the end of method definition, you can find something like:

```
return this.unbind('click.prettyphoto').bind('click.prettyphoto',$.prettyPhoto.initialize);
```

So the proper unbind without losing other click-related event handlers would be (generally for all links):

```
jQuery('a').unbind('click.prettyphoto');
```

**For your specific selector:**

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").unbind('click.prettyphoto');
```