# jquery + AJAX + double calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building an ajax based navigation and everything works fine, except one thing:

When i look in Firebug I can see that on each click the ajax site gets called and loaded twice.

This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Check if url hash value exists (for bookmark)
    $.history.init(pageload);   

    //highlight the selected link
    $('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');

    //Seearch for link with REL set to ajax
    $('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {

        //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;

        //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

        //for back button
        $.history.load(hash);   

        //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //hide the main and show the progress bar
        $('#main').hide();
        $('#loading').show();


        //run the ajax
        getPage();

        //cancel the anchor tag behaviour
        return false;
    }); 
});

//AJAX Navigation Helper function
function pageload(hash) {

    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
}

//AJAX Navigation Helper function   
function getPage() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);

    $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {  

            //hide the progress bar
            $('#loading').hide();   

            //add the main retrieved from ajax and put it in the #main div
            $('#main').html(html);

            //display the body with fadeIn transition
            $('#main').fadeIn('slow');      

            //reload site scripts
            $.getScript("js/script.js"); 

        }       
    });

}
```

So whenever I click on a list in my navigation, the page gets loaded just fine into #main, but it happens twice (as displayed in Firebug). Any1 maybe has an idea why? :)

I noticed that it doesnt happen when i access a certain page by url (than it only does one ajax call), so I guess the problem is somewhere in the click function.

p.s. i am using the jquery history plugin, but I dont think the problem is there, or?

Comment: Well, how many times is `getPage` being called -- and why?

Comment: Its being called once in the click function to get the content and once in the pageload function in case the user navigates to it directly via browser - I cant see the problem there :(

Comment: Does your jQuery code lie inside any dynamically loaded/modified content (i.e. content loaded from an AJAX request, a modal popup region, etc?).

Comment: No not realy. Whole code is at bottom of the page in seperate files and some part directly in the page.

Comment: find best answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to guess that getPage is called twice. Put a debugger statement at the beginning of the function (debugger;) and open firebug to see if it is. Here's one way to fix the problem if it is getting called twice:

```
//AJAX Navigation Helper function   
function getPage() {

    if(getPage.isLoaded != true) {

        //generate the parameter for the php script
        var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);

        $.ajax({
            url: "loader.php",  
            type: "GET",        
            data: data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {  

                //hide the progress bar
                $('#loading').hide();   

                //add the main retrieved from ajax and put it in the #main div
                $('#main').html(html);

                //display the body with fadeIn transition
                $('#main').fadeIn('slow');      

                //reload site scripts
                $.getScript("js/script.js"); 

            }       
        });

    }

    getPage.isLoaded = true;

}
```

Comment: Alright, I think that does work once I set getPage.isLoaded back on false on click. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

I believe your click event is bubbling to the anchor.

try:

```
    $('a[rel=ajax]').click(function (event) {

        //cancel the anchor tag behaviour
        event.preventDefault();

        //grab the full url
        var hash = this.href;

        //remove the # value
        hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

        //for back button
        $.history.load(hash);   

        //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
        $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //hide the main and show the progress bar
        $('#main').hide();
        $('#loading').show();


        //run the ajax
        getPage();


    });
```

Edit:  simply returning false won't cancel a jquery bound event.

Edit: @wildrot is right

Comment: Actually, you should do the event.preventDefault() before anything else. Some "browsers" manage to proceed with the event before they even get to the preventDefault().

Comment: Thanks you two! Unfortunately its still doing 2 calls when I click a link. No matter where i put the event.preventDefault(). And only one call when I navigate to the page directly via URL.

Comment: Just speculating, but could it be that the history plugin is doing a second call each time to "cache" the newly loaded content?

Answer (score 1):

Just speculating, but … Does the stuff you load via AJAX by any chance contain the same script again?

Comment: Hi, No the stuff contains html code only and the getScript calls a script.js, which has 0 content yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
$('a[rel=ajax]').die('click').click(function (event) { -> will load once..
```

Hope this helps