# Javascript/Jquery click enable

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code's else part isnt working, i.e. click is not getting enabled.

```
if

    $("#section1").click(function(event){
        return false;
    });

else

    $("#section1").click(function(event){
        return true;
    });
```

So basically, I want to remove the click functionality over a certain div section, which is working fine but while returning the click functionality back it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: your code isn't complete. You've missed the conditional statement on the `if`.

Comment: @locrizak pretty crap psuedo code if it doesn't even mention what the condition should be ;)

Comment: @locrizak, "pseudo code" is the correct spelling, and even pseudo code can be blatantly incorrect. You can't expect to ask a question on StackOverflow to debug an issue by posting the pseudo code. At some point *real* code needs to be used to solve *real* problems. Also, don't ever call me "brah".

Comment: Im just saying in this situation it doesn;t matter what the conditions are. He wants to know how to add and remove an event listener in an if statement. And my bad I knoew it was spelt like that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to remove the click event rather than add another one that returns true.

Try (instead of the else bit):

```
$('#section1').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Correct, and this elaborates on this point a bit more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You need to unbind the `click` event. The reason being is if say this block of code gets called 3 times, that is putting 3 event handlers on `#selection1` and each time it is clicked all three of those functions are called.

```
if
    $("#section1").unbind('click');

else
    $("#section1").bind('click', function(event){
        return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#section1").click(function(event){
        return false;
    });
```

will disable its functionality

```
$("#section1").unbind('click')
```

will remove attached click event and let it do its work

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#section1").click(function(event){
    return false;
});
```

This will disable the click event from happening, whereas `true` continues the click event, I'm not sure what you want to achieve but you can use [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to attach an event, like so:

```
$("#section1").bind('click', function(){
    alert('You clicked on it');
});
```

But to remove a click event, you would use the opposite; [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).