# jQuery: how to stop propagation to the same handler?

Tags: jquery, events

Consider the following code:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
  console.log("Ok");
});

$(document).add($('p')).click(function onceHandler(event) {
  console.log('Clicked.');
});
```

I would like to make the `onceHandler` run only once when "p" is clicked, so each handler should run once instead of the second one running twice due to the click propagating from p to document.

`event.stopPropagation()` will break the first handler, so I can't use it. I've also tried:

```
$(document).add($('p')).click(function(event) {
  if (event.stopDoingThat) return;
  console.log('Clicked.');
  event.stopDoingThat = true;
});
```

which didn't work. So basically without changing anything I'm getting 2 "clicked" and one "ok". With `stopPropagation` - 1 "clicked", what I need is 1 "clicked" and 1 "ok"

Comment: Here's a generic solution using just JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114978/stop-event-propagation-for-a-specific-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work in all browsers, but I tested it in chrome.

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
  console.log("ok");
});

$(document).add($('p')).click(function onceHandler(event) {
    if(!event.originalEvent.myClickDone){
        console.log("click");    
    }

    event.originalEvent.myClickDone = true;
});
```

Basically, both `event` objects share a common `originalEvent`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a perfect use case for the `one` function from jQuery:

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The
>   handler is executed at most once per element.

In your case, this would translate to something like the following code:

```
$(document).add($('p')).one('click', function onceHandler(event) {
    console.log('Clicked.');
});
```

More information on is to be found in [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: I wanted the handler to execute many times for each element, just so that 1 click doesn't call it twice. Thanks for the suggestion though, I didn't know about this function

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var firstRun = true;

$(document).click(function (event) {
  console.log("Ok");
});

$(document).add($('p')).click(function onceHandler(event) {
  if(firstRun) {
    console.log('Clicked.');
    firstRun = false;
  }
});
```

There is probably a more elegant solution. Something along the lines of:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
  console.log("Ok");
});

$(document).add($('p')).on("click.runonce", function(event) {
    console.log('Clicked.');
    $(document).off("click.runonce");
  }
});
```

Referenced from this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Comment: The first one will only work the first time, I need both handlers run each time

Comment: Ah right, my mistake, presumed that from the name `onceHandler` that you only wanted this event to fire once.

Comment: Hey, your second solution actually does work after the "runonce" change. Have never heard about namespaced events before!

Comment: Very handy if you are adding and removing events from the same items

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you use the apply function on the document-object twice instead of on the paragraph-object. Change your last line so that it look like this:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
  console.log("Ok");
});

$(document).add($('p').click(function onceHandler(event) {
    console.log('Clicked.');
    $('p').off('click');
  }
}));
```

Comment: That was done on purpose, I can't just change the code this way

Answer (score 0):

Does this not do the job? I think you could make things simple with a single event handler and the testing of the target element:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "p") {
       console.log("clicked");
    }
    console.log("ok");
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PkyjJ/)