# Stop Event Propagation for a Specific Handler

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

### tl;dr Summary

Write a function that—when registered to handle a specific event on multiple elements in a hierarchy—executes on the first element reached during bubbling but does not execute (or returns early) when bubbling further up the hierarchy. (Without actually stopping propagation of the event.)

### Simple Example

Given [this HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/wun8k/)…

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div><button>click</button></div>
<script>
var d = document.querySelector('div'),
    b = document.querySelector('button');
d.addEventListener('mousedown',clickPick,false);
d.addEventListener('mousedown',startDrag,false);
b.addEventListener('mousedown',startDrag,false);
function clickPick(){ console.log('click',this.tagName); }
function startDrag(){ console.log('drag',this.tagName);  }
</script>
```

…clicking on the button yields this output:

> drag BUTTON
> click DIV
> drag DIV

However, I don't want to drag the div. Specifically, I want `startDrag` to only be processed once, on the `<button>`, the leaf-most element for which it is registered in a particular propagation chain.

### "Working" solution

The following JavaScript code [has been tested](http://jsfiddle.net/PLcZv/) to *work* on IE9, Chrome18, Firefox11, Safari5, and Opera11.

```js
function startDrag(evt){
  if (seenHandler(evt,startDrag)) return;
  console.log('drag',this.tagName);
}

function seenHandler(evt,f){
  if (!evt.handlers) evt.handlers=[];
  for (var i=evt.handlers.length;i--;) if (evt.handlers[i]==f) return true;
  evt.handlers.push(f);
  return false;
}
```

*The above does **not** work with IE8, even if you use the global `window.event` object; the same `event` object is not reused during bubbling.*

### The Question(s)

However, I'm not sure if the above is *guaranteed* to work…nor if it's as elegant as it could be.

1. Is the same `event` object guaranteed to be passed up the chain during propagation?
2. Is the `event` object guaranteed to never be re-used for different event dispatches?
3. Is the `event` object guaranteed to support having an expando property added to it?
4. Can you think of a more elegant way to detect if the same event handler function has been seen already on the current dispatch of an event?

### Real World Application

Imagine this SVG hierarchy…

```
<g>
  <rect … />
  <rect … />
  <circle … />
</g>
```

…and [a user who wants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095979/d3-click-and-drag-event-nesting) to be able to drag the whole group by dragging on any rect within it, and also to be able to drag just the circle by dragging on it.

Now mix in a [generic dragging library](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-behavior#wiki-drag) that handles most of the details for you. I'm proposing to modify this library such that if the user adds a drag handler to both the `<g>` and the `<circle>` then dragging on the circle automatically prevents the dragging from initiating on the group, but without stopping propagation of all `mousedown` events (since the user might have a high level handler for other purposes that is desirable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic solution that works in the current versions of all major browsers...but not in IE8 and may not be *guaranteed* to work in future versions:

```
// Solution supporting arbitrary number of handlers
function seenFunction(evt,f){
  var s=evt.__seenFuncs;
  if (!s) s=evt.__seenFuncs=[];
  for (var i=s.length;i--;) if (s[i]===f) return true;
  evt.handlers.push(f);
  return false;
}

// Used like so:
function myHandler(evt){
  if (seenHandler(evt,myHandler)) return;
  // ...otherwise, run code normally
}
```

Alternatively, here is a less-generic solution that is slightly-but-probably-not-noticeably faster (again, not in IE8 and maybe not *guaranteed* to work in the future):

```
// Implemented per handler; small chance of error with a conflicting name
function myHandler(evt){
  if (evt.__ranMyHandler) return;
  // ...otherwise, run code normally
  evt.__ranMyHandler = true;
}
```

*I will happily switch the acceptance to another answer with proper specs provided.*

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/3vprA/3/) looks good in Firefox, and can probably be adapted to non-standard browsers, since jQuery essentially does this with `delegate` and `live`.  It uses [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) and [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) , both of which are standard.

```
var d = document.querySelector('div'),
    b = document.querySelector('button');
d.addEventListener('mousedown',clickPick,false);
d.addEventListener('mousedown',startDrag,false);
function clickPick(evt){
    console.log('click', this.tagName);
}
function startDrag(evt){
    console.log('drag', evt.target.tagName);
    evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

For me, the order when you click on the button is reversed.  Yours has "drag BUTTON" then "click DIV", while mine is the opposite.  However, I think it's undefined in the original.

EDIT: Changed to use `target`.  IE before 9 uses a non-standard `srcElement` property that means the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I seem to have simplified the use case too far. Given a set of registrations for the same event on different elements in a hierarchy and different handlers, with no control over the order of registration or choice of elements, I need a way for a specific handler to run itself only for the first (lowest) element it hits in the chain.

Comment: @Phrogz, if your real case is that general, I probably can't help you.  However, if you make your example more realistic (without trying to cover every theoretical possibility), I'll try to adapt my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear about the real world needs.