# How to block all request inside a <iFrame>

Tags: javascript, iframe

We need to block all requests inside a page loaded in an IFRAME tag.
The page are located in the same domain, but we need to prevent the navigation in the inside page.
Obviously, we don't know the elements in the inner page. They may be links (anchor link) Javascript calls, JQuery calls, Ajax calls, From submit and so on.

Here is the way we can handle simple  tags and standard submit of a form:

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$(this).submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

For example the first function work good but it is only an  tag, but if the  is triggered using JQuery that function does not work.

The second work fine only for standard form submit, but not Ajax submits.

Is there a way to handle all the events?

Comment: Is this frame loaded via JS/AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Or

```
$('*').unbind('click');
$('[href]').attr('href', '')
```

See this interesting answer: [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply overlay a transprent `<div>` over the same area as the iframe. The iframe would load as normal but you should not be able to interact with it.

Comment: TAB, TAB, TAB, Enter.  Now I've interacted with it.

Comment: @Deestan and you'd have to keep tabbing to get to the link you wanted to click. I'm not saying it's impossible to circumvent just pretty hard work and the average user using a pointing device is unlikely to know it or want to put in the effort.

Comment: Of course it's less accessible, but that's not what you said.  :)  The phrasing "[...] you should not be able to interact with it" is incorrect.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, I'm not certain a enter key press would trigger an on-click event in all possible situations but in particular in the example the questioner gave. My reply still stands valid for most users, and may be all that is required to meet the demand behind to the question. It's a pretty simple, and fairly robust solution to the problem anyway.