# jQuery Div.Click(): abandon/change Function after function executed several times

Tags: jquery, function, click

Let's say I have two `div`, `#move`  and `#object` respectively,

and a function thats move `#object` when click on `#move`

```
$("#move").click(function(){
$("#object").animate({
    "left": "+=1px"
}
  );
    })
```

How can I abandon or change the Function after
it had been executed **a particular number of times** using `.Keyup()` event or something?

Comment: What do you mean by "abandon" the function?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = 0;
$("#move").on('click', function(){
   count++;
   $("#object").animate({
     "left": "+=1px"
   });
})
```

**Suppose, if you want to off the animation event when key up occurs on any input**

```
$('SOME_ELEMENT').on('keyup', function() {  // SOME_ELEMENT is any valid selector

   if(count === 3) { // I assume after 3 times animation you will unbind/off it
     $('#move').unbind('click');  //  or $('#move').off('click');
   }

});
```

**Suppose, if you want to off the animation event when use press *ESC* key**

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {

     if(e.which === 27 && count === 3) { // 27 is keycode of ESC key
        $('#move').off('click');
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `.unbind()` method, which removes event handlers.