# Event handler binding and unbinding with ajax loaded pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

What's the "well threaded path" for handling JavaScript events in dynamically loaded (ajax) pages.

I have an app which has a tab bar controller that pulls in the sub-views through ajax, and these views have their own js, which is fine the first time round, but if someone were to use the app for a long time and cycle through all the tab views repeatedly, the events would keep getting bound over and over again which seems horribly inefficient, especially considering that these sub-views might have their own sub-views which they manage, some of which could have lots of event handlers.

What are some of more elegant approaches to solving this? (BTW, I'm using jQuery)

Comment: Use on() and off() functions instead. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scenario, and you didn't show even one line of code, but you can use `unbind` before you bind new callback:

```
$('#foo').unbind('click').click(handler);
...
$('#foo').unbind('click').click(handler)
...
$('#foo').unbind('click').click(handler)
...

$('#foo').click(); // handler fire one time only.
```