# How do I unbind and rebind on() click animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a recursive loop that does a simple animation.  These animations are controlled by on page load & onclick of controls `.carousel_item`.

**[LIVE SAMPLE JSFIDDLES CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VFqTW/27/)** *stripped down for simplicity purposes*

**Problem:**  When Repeat clicking on the same control the animation will fire over and over.  I would like the animation to only fire once per `carousel_item`.

**UPDATE**I would like the animation to only fire once per `carousel_item`. And reset when the following `carousel_item` is clicked.

EXAMPLE:  Pushing 1 repeatedly will trigger the animation over and over again. I would like the first press to trigger the animation once.  Next User mashes 2 this will retrigger the animation once and not repeatedly.  User can still push 1 again for the mashing is all I want to prevent

Logically, I see the click unbinding itself and rebinding itself on click of another `.carousel_item`  that's my logic; however, I'm sure there's a better solution

```
var carItems = $('.carousel_item');
var sideitems = $('.side_item');
var x = false;
$(sideitems).hide();
fadeItem();

$(carItems).on({
    click: function () {

        $(sideitems).stop(true, true).animate({
            right: '4.5em'
        });
        $(sideitems).hide();

        fadeItem();

    },
    mouseenter: function () {

    },
    mouseleave: function () {

    }
});


function fadeItem() {
    $('.side_ul li:hidden:first').fadeIn(fadeItem).animate({
        right: '-4.5em'
    }, 150, function () {});;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="carousel_item"> <img src="asset/img/1600/slide1_1600.jpg" /> </li>
        <li class="carousel_item"> <img src="asset/img/1600/slide2_1600.jpg" /> </li>
        <li class="carousel_item"> <img src="asset/img/1600/slide1_1600.jpg" /> </li>
        <li class="carousel_item"> <img src="asset/img/1600/slide2_1600.jpg" /> </li>
        <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
      </ul>
    </div>

      <nav class="side_nav">
    <ul class="side_ul">
        <li class="side_item home"><div class="text_links"><a href="#">home</a></div></li>
        <li class="side_item document"><div class="text_links"><a href="#">docs</a></div></li>
        <li class="side_item video"><div class="text_links"><a href="#">video</a></div></li>        
        <li class="side_item programming"><div class="text_links"><a href="#">web</a></div></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
```

[image]
**[LIVE SAMPLE JSFIDDLES CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VFqTW/27/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ScbDG/2/

You can use `.off` after click event; http://api.jquery.com/off/ & `$(this)` will make sure that its set to `off` for that particular object.

Good read: [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Hope this helps, `:)`

**code**

```
$(carItems).on({
     click: function () {

         $(sideitems).stop(true, true).animate({
             right: '4.5em'
         });
         $(sideitems).hide();

         fadeItem();
         $(this).off('click');

     },
     mouseenter: function () {

     },
     mouseleave: function () {

     }



 });
```

Comment: maybe one() is appropriate here?

Comment: @akonsu I thought about it but might be mathew (OP) needs **late binding** after turning it `off`, .one will make it only one time clickable `:)` although good idea, OP might want to **read this in that case:** http://api.jquery.com/one/ **+1** to your comment man!

Comment: @Tats_innit maybe I am missing something but your code is also one time clickable because you remove the click handler at the end.

Comment: @akonsu howz it going man! With jQuery 1.7 onward the event API has been updated, .bind()/.unbind() are still available for backwards compatibility, but the preferred method is using the on()/off() functions. `:)` but still can be bind back again, lemme know if I missed anything or not clear `:)` using `.off` on the `$(this)` carousel will achieve that and unbind the event we can bind it back again though depending the cause

Comment: Also one() would not work with this pretty syntax :) but it does otherwise do the same.

Comment: @Mahn Indeed I concur bruv `:)` depending on OP need [ Bizinga ] x 2 times `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit how would get the toggle of "on/off"? I must turn them back on?  to reuse them just the same one cant be pressed more then once

Comment: I essentially want to prevent users from mashing the sames .carosole_item and making the animation reset over and over.  I need the flow of the orginal jsfiddles.