# Why does text of previous links clicked on the page show up in an AJAX request?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here's a bootstrap modal that I'm putting the result of AJAX request in

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  $('div.divBox a').click(function(){
    var vendor = $(this).text();
    console.log(vendor);
    $('#myModal').on('show', function(){          
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ip.php",
        data: "id=" + vendor,
        success: function(html){
          $("#modal-body").html(html);              
        }
      });           
    });
  });
  $('#myModal').on('hide', function () {
    $("#modal-body").empty();
    <?php unset($_GET); ?>;
  })
</script>
```

the **ip.php** file is

The anchor links code looks like this

```
           <tbody>
              <?php foreach ($rowarr as $k => $v) { ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $k ?></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="divBox">
                      <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
```

$k is a number. $v is a name with spaces and special characters.

console.log(vendor) shows me the text of the link I clicked in CDT. But the output of the modal changes. It goes through all the links text I clicked previously, and keeps replacing them and finally ends up at the most current link text.

So if clicked the links in this order the console output looks like this

```
Microsoft Corporation
IBM Corp
Hewlett-Packard
Apple
```

The text in the modal will start out as

```
Array ( [id] => Microsoft Corporation )
```

then replace with

```
Array ( [id] => IBM Corp )
```

then replace with

```
Array ( [id] => Hewlett-Packard)
```

then end up with

```
Array ( [id] => Apple )
```

What is keeping track of the links clicked on the page ? Do I need to reset it every time a new link is clicked ?

EDIT: In response to "What have you tried?"

I added the `$("#modal-body").empty();` in there in hope that maybe it's the modal body that I need to cleared. That wasn't it. Then I thought maybe the GET variable need to be reset on closing of the modal, so I added the `<?php unset($_GET); ?>;`. But the print_r($_GET) shows that the array only contains one array element, not all the links clicked previously. So I can't figure where else the history of the links clicked be stored.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @Matt - I added the `$("#modal-body").empty();` in there in hope that maybe it's the modal body that I need to cleared. That wasn't it. Then I thought maybe the GET variable need to be reset on closing of the modal, so I added the `<?php unset($_GET); ?>;`. But the print_r($_GET) shows that the array only contains one array element, not all the links clicked previously. So I can't figure where else the history of the links clicked be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, each time you click a `divBox` link, it adds a new handler to the `myModal` 'show' event. So basically after clicking 5 different`divBox` links, `myModal`'s show event will cycle through 5 different handler functions.

Basically you need to remove the previously added 'show' handler before adding a new one.

```
$('#myModal').off('show');
```

[Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Comment: MAN! you are the man! Wish I could upvote you more. I wasn't even sure how to explain the problem or if I had explained it correctly.