# Keep the current nav button active

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have the following code for a button in my nav menu:

```
div onmouseover=\"changeBGColor(this,'#b90707');changeColor(this,'#fff');\" onmouseout=\"changeBGColor(this,'');changeColor(this,'#333');\" onClick="" class='navbtn'>Entry /div
```

And the following code to keep the element active:

```
  $('.navbtn').each(function(){
    var path = window.location.href;
    var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var url = $(this).attr('onClick').substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+18,$(this).attr('onClick').length-1);

    if(url == current ){
        changeBGColor(this,'#b90707');changeColor(this,'#fff');
        $(this).onmouseout = '';
        $(this).onmouseover= '';
    };
});
```

The element remains active until i move the mouse over the element. I would like to remain active anytime no matter where i move my mouse on..

Comment: Why do you set an `mouseout`-event at all if you don't need it? And please don't use inline handler in the elements attributes. It  makes the code much harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

That code appears to be changing the background color in the `onmouseout` handler. If this reverts the color to what it was, try not handling that event to see if it stays the same.

**Edit:**
Setting the handler to the empty string doesn't look right. See [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

**Edit:**

Something like this might be better:

```
$(this).unbind('mouseleave');
```

Or (according to the above link, this is the preferred approach):

```
$(this).off('mouseleave');
```

**Edit:**

For this to work you will need to remove the inline handlers you have set up for `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`. The reason for this is that `$(this).off('mouseleave');` won't work unless the events are wired up with jQuery, and `$(this).onmouseover= '';` won't work either for the same reason.

You will then need to wire up the event handlers with some jQuery:

```
$('.navbtn').mouseover(function () {
    changeBGColor(this,'#b90707'); 
});

$('.navbtn').mouseout(function () {
    changeBGColor(this, '');
});
```

Now where you are currently doing:

```
if(url == current ){ 
    changeBGColor(this,'#b90707');changeColor(this,'#fff'); 
    $(this).onmouseout = ''; 
    $(this).onmouseover= ''; 
};
```

You can instead do:

```
if(url == current ){ 
    changeBGColor(this,'#b90707');changeColor(this,'#fff'); 
    $('.navbtn').off('mouseout');
    $('.navbtn').off('mouseover'); 
};
```

Which should ensure that the colors you have just set stay that way.

Note that jQuery 1.7+ is required for the `off` syntax to work.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what didn't work? The example I posted worked fine for me.

Comment: @EmilDumbazu it would also be useful if you could edit your question with the code that you have tried but doesn't work.