# Disable click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this function:

```
function pre_move_callback(anchor){
 $('#etichette div').fadeOut(800);
 $(anchor).delay(800).fadeIn(1800);
}
```

I need to disable the click event in two divs named "freccia_sx" and "freccia_dx" while fading out. How can I?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean remove a click handler or stop the click event from propagating?

Answer (score 3):

Returning false from an event callback prevents this event to be sent further on :

```
$('#freccia_sx, #freccia_dx').click(function() {return false;});
```

If you want to remove a handler, take a look at this post :

[Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)