# How to remove toggle event?

Tags: jquery

Hey i've set a toggle event on an element and i wish to remove it somewhere in the code.

How can i remove this?

This is my toggle :

```
$('#album_cell'+currentCell).toggle(function() {                                    

                    $('#album_cell'+currentCell).flip({
                    direction:'lr',
                    dontChangeColor: true,
                    content: captionPane
                    });
                        }, function() {
                    $('#album_cell'+currentCell).revertFlip();
                    });
```

flip is a plugin i'm using, unrelated to the problem.

I can't seem to be able to use something like :

```
$('#album_cell'+currentCell).off('toggle');
```

So how can i disable it? could i set both of the toggle events as some variables and disable it then?

Comment: Not sure, but event shouldn't be defined with .on() to use .off()?

Comment: Makes sense, but that's the best i could come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 'toggle' is action and not event. Try to remove 'click' event. See [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/210345/926620)

```
$('#album_cell'+currentCell).off('click');
```

See also examples [JQuery.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to disable specific action.

Comment: That's not working. and i have read all of that before posting, none seem to answer my question.

Comment: Try $('#album_cell'+currentCell).unbind('click');

Comment: unbind is being deparcted, off is instead. and Ok it works i had a syntax error, thanks anton

Comment: This is because I don't write it in my answer. You can try to disable all events with $('#album_cell'+currentCell).off(); EDIT: Ah... ok.