# Wordpress AJAX Temporarily disable click event when it is still loading

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#myid').click(function() {   

    var data = {
            action: 'xxx_ajax_response',
            xxx_ajax_response_nonce: the_ajax_script.xxx_ajax_response_nonce    
        };      
    //do an ajax request

    $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $(this).next().slideToggle();   

    });

    //return false;
});
```

How to temporarily disable click event when AJAX function is still executing/loading? But restore click after successful AJAX loading? I have tried with changing class but I'm using id selector and does not work. Is there an easy method? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a flag variable outside of the `click` callback function:

```
var _doing_ajax = false;
$('#myid').click(function() {   
    if ( _doing_ajax ) {
        return false;
    }
    var data = {
            action: 'xxx_ajax_response',
            xxx_ajax_response_nonce: the_ajax_script.xxx_ajax_response_nonce    
        };      

    _doing_ajax = true;
    //do an ajax request
    $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $(this).next().slideToggle();   
        _doing_ajax = false;
    });

    //return false;
});
```

Basically you define a new local variable, with default value set to `false`. At the beginning of the `.click()` callback function, you check the value of the flag variable - if it's true, you return false. Just before starting the AJAX request, you set the variable to `true`. Once the AJAX call is completed, you set the variable to `false` again, so that any further clicks will enable the AJAX again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [unbind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind) to remove the event from the element while loading, and after loading the data [bind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind) it again. You write the `bind` function inside the `success` of the `$.post()` [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

This post may help [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)