# Unexpected order in script execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it running the second script and how can I make it work like a toggle control?

```
<script>
    var el = 2;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".rightDiv").click(function(){
            if (el == 2) {
                $(this).animate({left:'150px'});
                el = 1;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".rightDiv").click(function(){
            if (el==1) {
                $(this).animate({left:'50px'});
                el = 2;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's running both statements because you've attached 2 `click` callbacks. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery for how to remove the current event handlers before you attach new ones.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one .ready()

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
  var el = false; 
  var rightDivs = $('.rightDiv');
  $(rightDivs).click(function(){ 
      if (el == false) 
      { 
        $(this).animate({left:'150px'}); 
        el = true; 
      }
      else if (el == true)
      {
         $(this).animate({left:'50px'}); 
        el = false;
      }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you:

```
var el = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rightDiv").click(function() {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({left: (el ? 50 : 150) + 'px'});
        el = !el;
    });
});​
```

[**jsfiddle with example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sjwEe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have atteached two event handlers, so when the event happens it will run one, then the other.

As the first one will change the variable so that the condition in the second one becomes true, the code inside both `if` statements will run.

Put the code in the same event handler, so that you can use `else` to run only one of them:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var el = 2;

    $(".rightDiv").click(function(){
      if (el == 2) {
        $(this).animate({left:'150px'});
        el = 1;
      } else {
        $(this).animate({left:'50px'});
        el = 2;
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[here's](http://jsfiddle.net/sjwEe/2/) a slightly improved version of @h2ooooooo 's answer, where we ditched the global scoped variable and use element's attributes.

Basically what we are doing here is to prevent bloating the global scope by using global variables and now we are working with data directly related to the element that was pressed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rightDiv").attr("isLeft",1).click(function() {
        var pos = "50";
        if( $(this).attr("isLeft") == "1" ){
            pos = "150";
            $(this).attr("isLeft",0)
        }else{
            $(this).attr("isLeft",1);
        }
        $(this).stop(true).animate({left: pos + 'px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: You should definitely use `.data()` for this solution instead of `.attr()` (and besides - you shouldn't set a custom attribute without prepending `data-` to it).