# jquery undo a function bind

Tags: jquery

I am using the following with an address picker.

HTML

```
<form>
<input id="searchByLoc" type='checkbox' >
<input id="searchQuery" type='text' >
<input type="submit' value="search">
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#searchByLoc:checkbox ').live('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var addresspicker=$(this).addresspicker();//alert('checked');
    } else {
         //I want to un initialize the addresspicker() on the input field
         var addresspicker=die($(this).addresspicker());//alert('un-checked');
    }
});
```

I am having some trouble with the ELSE part above. If the check box is unchecked, how can I stop the initialization so that no location is suggested?

Comment: I'm confused, isn't just remove the else?

Comment: Well, no. bcz the input field is intended to be used for both search by name as well as location. so, if a search is done for location and then a search for name is about to be done, I would like to have no location suggestions.

Comment: I don't think that unbinding the change event is what you want, but instead handle in your `adresspicker()` if it's checked or not...

Comment: yeah exactly. its a plugin i forked, and not sure how to undo the function working on the input field

Comment: So give us more info. Who's the plugin? What adresspicker do?

Comment: @SérgioMichels http://xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html

Comment: Looking at the [jQuery UI docs](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory), it looks like you want to `destroy` it. `.addresspicker("destroy")`. Not sure if that's handled by the base widget or if the plugin has to manually define its own `destroy` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use unbind() function of jquery. It will remove the event. [jquery bind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

You can see this post also for best usage [best way to remove events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

below jquery 1.7

```
$('#yourDomElement').unbind('click');
```

jquery 1.7+

```
$('#yourDomElement').off('click');
```

Comment: Note if using jQuery 1.7+ it is suggested you use `on()`/`off()` instead of `live()`/`unbind()`.

Comment: What would he be unbinding?

Comment: what should I unbind? I tried addresspicker.unbind(); not working

Comment: @Ravi, unbinding the domelement is not stopping the already initialized input field from suggesting addresses as the user inputs text