# How can I NOT trigger window.onhashchange on certain clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons, A and B. On clicking A the hashtag changes and I want to call the `window.onhashchange` function. But, on clicking B, I am manually appending a hashtag to the URL. In the later case, I don't want `window.onhashchange` to be triggered.

Comment: Can't you ignore the hashtag in function? Or remove hashchange handler before changing and append it back on done?

Comment: @Vyktor How can i remove hashchange handler before changing and append it back on done?

Comment: @Fred i hav tried a lotta things like using a counter. my page is loaded once and then i am manipulating it rest of the time. actually i want to capture the back and forward button click. and i am manually updating the hashtags. i dont want window.onhashchange to interfere in these occassions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I'm assuming you have generated HTML by PHP something along this:

```
<ul id='list-of-links'>
    <li id='A'><a href="#posA">Link A</a></li>
    <li id='B'><a href="#posB">Link B</a></li>
</ul>
```

Having that you wish that A does something else than B. In your JavaScript you can use the hash function.

```
var targetHash = window.location.hash.slice(1);

if( targetHash != 'posB' ) {
    //do something as it's not 'posB'
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: -1, Based on [javascipt operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) is `!targetHash` evaluated before `==`, therefore you are doing `False == 'posB'` and why not to use `!=` directly?

Comment: Yea was my mistake, too much of a quick answer without proper testing, thanks for removing downvote.

Comment: thanks a lot guys! i found the answer to this.. https://developers.google.com/tv/web/articles/location-hash-navigation#detect-loc-hash can help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without any code all I can suggest is to check the id of the button that causes the event and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

With little help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/210345/1149736) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441/1149736) you can temporary remove event handles. Here's [working example of jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/JXY5B/) with `click` event so assuming `jQuery >= 1.8` it'll be similar, thus something like this:

```
// Initialization, add some events
$.hashchange(...);

// Store event handles for hashchange
hashchange_handles = [];
$.each( $._data($('#foo').get(0), "events")['hashchange'], function(i,handle){
    // alert(handle.handler);
    hashchange_handles.push(handle.handler);
});

// Remove handles
$.off('hashchange');

// Do your stuff here

// Restore event handler
length = hashchange_handles.length;
for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    $.hashchange( hashchange_handles[i]);
}
```

It worked for `click` so hopefully it'll work for `hashchange`.

<sub>Note: I know the code is not perfect, you should tuned it. Plus I have tested it only for `click`.</sub>

Comment: hey thanks @Vyktor...i'll try this... btw is there any way to detect the source of hashchange?

Comment: @spyder I doubt so, but you won't loose anything by googling for a while :)