# jquery check every 2 minutes if there was a click or mousemove event

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I need to refresh a page after 10 minutes of inactivity.

What I mean by inactivity : no mouse move and/or no clicks on the body

Here's what I have so far **(that piece of code is working fine)**

```
idleTime = 0;

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;

    if (idleTime > 10) {
    window.location.reload();
    }
}

$j(document).ready( function(e) {
    var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 60000); // 1 min

    $j(this).mousemove(function () {
        idleTime = 0;
    });

    $j(this).click(function () {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
}
```

What I dont like here, is the fact that its reseting the timer on every single mousemove event. And Im worried about performance.

What I would like is something like : Check every 2 minutes if the mouse position changed. If yes increment timer. Not sure how to do that.

Any help?

Comment: You can't get the coordinates without an event... so the code would look something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a flag variable (eg: hasMouseMoved), update it on the mousemove handler and [remove the event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery), then whenever the timer fires change the code to:

```
if ((idleTime > 10) || (idleTime%2==0 && hasMouseMoved))
{
      window.location.reload();
}
```