# Jquery .click() building up a queue

Tags: jquery

So I have this function :

call up functions :

```
function tog_1(){
        $('.upload').dequeue().stop(true, true).hide(400);
        $('.post').dequeue().stop(true, true).show(400);
    }
    function tog_2(){
        $('.upload').dequeue().stop(true, true).show(400);
        $('.post').dequeue().stop(true, true).hide(400);
    }

 $(".status").on("click",".sts",function(){// status upload
            tog_1();
$(".post").click(function(){
                var message = $(".sts").val();
                if ((jQuery.trim( message) ).length!=0)
                {
                    $.post("load/post.php",{message : message, poster : <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['id']); ?> , id : <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['id']); ?> },
                        function(result){
                            $(".sts").css({"background":"rgba(255,255,255,0.5)","color":"rgba(0,0,0,0.3)","font-weight":"bold"});
                            $(".sts").animate({height:"20px"},"slow");
                            $(".sts").val("How do you feel?");
                            tog_2();
                            $('#history_t tr:first').fadeIn("slow").before(result);
                        });
                }
    });
        });
```

on this html:

```
<table class="upload" width="100%" height="30px">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="33%" valign="middle" current="1" nr_crt="1" class="sts_td" align="center"><p>Status</p></td>
                                <td width="33%" valign="middle" nr_crt="2" class="img_td" align="center"><p>Upload image</p></td>
                                <td width="33%" valign="middle" nr_crt="3" class="link_td" align="center"><p>Share link</p></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                        
                        <textarea name="status_write" class="sts" id="sts1" >How do you feel?</textarea>
                        <textarea name="image_upload" class="img" id="sts2">Drag and drop image.</textarea>
                        <textarea name="share_link" class="link" id="sts3">Share link.</textarea>
```

every time I press the textarea field the `$(".post").click()` builds up a queue and when I press post it sends the message to the database the number of times I have clicked the textarea field.... it's like the `$(".post").click()` builds up a queue,very strange.
How can I stop it ? Thank you.

Comment: You're adding `.post` click handler multiple times

Comment: and how can I stop adding it? I mean how can I prevent from adding it multiple times?

Comment: do you understand what it actually means? Could you explain what happens each time the `.status .sts` is clicked?

Comment: Yeah, I get an idea of what happens now that you put it like that, but I want to refresh the `.post` values everytime I click on the textarea field, if you know what I mean

Comment: right. You still didn't explain what happens on every `.status .sts` click. In the first line `tog_1();` is called. What's next? Why `$(".post").click(function(){ ... });` does need to be performed in a `.status .sts` click handler?

Comment: Because I have 3 textarea,and I want for each of them to have a post button (same button for all), without actually having to create 3 buttons, one for each textarea..

Comment: so? How does it explain requirement to have the handler assignment inside another handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$(".status").on("click",".sts",function(){
```

Is saying "run this function every time I click on an element matching `".sts"`.  And this code:

```
$(".post").click(function(){
```

Is saying "run this function every time I click on an element matching `".post"`.  So essentially, multiple clicks on `".sts"` results in:

- Run this function when I click `".post"`.
- And then run this other function when I click `".post"`.  (It doesn't matter that it's the same function.)
- And then run this other function when I click `".post"`.
- And then run this other function when I click `".post"`.

So when you click `".post"`, multiple functions run.

Since you're loading new content via AJAX and binding to that new content (which, I assume, contains `".post"` in this case), then you may have a couple of options.

You could [remove the click handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery) on `".post"` before adding a new one.  This could be as simple as adding something like this just before creating the click handler:

```
$('.post').off('click');
```

Or, depending on how the rest of your logic works, you may be able to use a deferred click handler for `".post"`, just like you're already using for `".sts"`.  It's not really clear from your code why you would *need* to re-bind the click handler instead of using a deferred handler attached to a common parent element.

Comment: amazing !!! you are a genius `$('.post').off('click');` is exactly what I was looking for :) thank you.

Comment: @CioroianuDenis you should really use delegation instead of using off()