# Remove click event handler from <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I'm having problem trying to remove the default click event handler from a  tag. I want in the end to add another handler. I tried the following but didn't work :

My HTML head

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

The html body

```
<aside id="content">
    <a id="goNext" href="/Home/NextPage?pageIndex=1">Next page</a> 

    <div>Page number : 0</div>
</aside>
```

The script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#goNext").unbind("click");
    $(window).off("click", "#goNext", false);
    $("#goNext").off("click");
</script>
```

NB : I'm using jQuery 2.0.3

Comment: I think you'll have to post more code. How are you binding the event handler in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Comment: @j08691 a typing error

Comment: If that's the whole script, *there's no click event bound to the link in the first place*. Seriously, you need to show the event you're trying to remove. If you're trying to prevent the link from navigating to the page in its href, go with Zac's answer.

Comment: @Juhana : I'm trying to remove the default handler

Comment: `$('#goNext').on('click', false);`

Comment: Yeah, ok, that's not a handler at all. It's just the default behavior. The first part of Zac's answer is correct then.

Comment: Since it handle a event (a click event), shouldn't we call it a handler ?

Comment: No. An event handler has a [specific meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) which doesn't include browser default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to stop the default click action from taking place:

```
$("#goNext").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Also put your jQuery in a ready statement: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#goNext").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I initially downvoted this, but I took it back. This might actually be what OP is asking; the question is totally unclear.

Comment: If the first part of your answer is correct. The second part obviously makes no sense at all.