# Cancel Click Event

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
enquire.register(value, {
  match: function () {
    $('nav.menu a[href="#"]').click(function () {
      $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    })
  },
  unmatch: function () {
  }
});
```

In unmatch, how can I cancel the click event which I set in match?

Comment: Did you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery ?

Comment: did you try `$(this).next('ul').untoggle();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll prefer to use a [namespaced click](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) event and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the handler

```
enquire.register(value, {
    match: function () {
        $('nav.menu a[href="#"]').on('click.match', function () {
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        })
    },
    unmatch: function () {
        $('nav.menu a[href="#"]').off('click.match');
    }
});
```