# jQuery: Disable onclick event using off() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do, I have code in HTML and my aim is to disable the three hyperlinks `#validate`,`#organize` and `#export`:

```
<p id="menuitems" class="inline textcenter">
                        <a id="import" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Import');">IMPORT</a> >> 
                        <a id="validate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Validate');">VALIDATE</a> >> 
                        <a id="organize" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Organize');">ORGANIZE</a> >> 
                        <a id="export" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Export');">EXPORT</a>
                    </p>
```

When I'm trying to call the following, nothing happend. I'm using jQuery 1.11.4 and I've read that the methods for disabling event listeners have changed since 1.7. So I would like to know if there is an error in my JavaScript code below or some new changes:

```
$('#validate').off('click');
$('#organize').off('click');
$('#export').off('click');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320195/jquery-html-disable-onclick

Comment: `off()` only works with events that were attached with `on()`. You're attempting to `off()` events that are attached inline through plain DOM attributes, and not via jQuery.

Comment: i used it as a replacement for the `unbind()` method that was used earlier. here i'm trying to disable the event without actually removing it.

Comment: Is it like a security feature? Maybe you should keep a flag as to whether those three events are "available", and check it in the body of `switchScreen()`. `return false;` in `switchScreen()` to bail out, and change the `onclick` attribute to `="return switchScreen('Screen');"`.

Comment: the `unbind()` method is not available as of jQuery 1.7 and bsically I'm looking for a way to just disable the listener so I don't have to reattach the functions associated with the event

Comment: There's no such thing as disabling a listener without removing it. Even if `.off()` worked, it would remove the listener, and you would have to re-attach it with `.on` later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to temporarily set the onclick to null, but store the original element onclick in the element or jquery object (e.g. `data`). With a helper function you can switch the elements on or off:

```
function setEnabled($a, Enabled ){
    $a.each(function(i, a){          
        var en = a.onclick !== null;        
        if(en == Enabled)return;
        if(Enabled){
            a.onclick = $(a).data('orgClick');            
        }
        else
        {
            $(a).data('orgClick',a.onclick);
            a.onclick = null;
        }
    });
}
```

Which can be called with something like:

```
setEnabled($('#validate'), false);
```

(also works on jquery objects with multiple elements because of the each)

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x53107fh/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind the click event (which was declared inline) as follows.

```js
document.getElementById("import").onclick = null;
document.getElementById("validate").onclick = null;
document.getElementById("organize").onclick = null;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="menuitems" class="inline textcenter">
  <a id="import" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Import');">IMPORT</a> >>
  <a id="validate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Validate');">VALIDATE</a> >>
  <a id="organize" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Organize');">ORGANIZE</a> >>
  <a id="export" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Export');">EXPORT</a>
</p>
```

Comment: this might be good for an answer, but I'm looking for a way to keep the event attached and just disable the listener

Comment: it is better to handle that `logic` inside the click `function`

Comment: it would be necessary to change the formatting also through editing the css within the function. not sure if a good idea.

Comment: or you may rebind the same click function as `document.getElementById("import").onclick = switchScreen('Import');`

Answer (score 0):

Event attached through javascript doesn't recognize by jquery, so javascript and jquery mixed approached can't work properly - that's the reason jquery
.off('click'); doesn't detach click event.

Modify html:

```
  <p id="menuitems" class="inline textcenter">
        <a id="import" href="javascript:void(0);">IMPORT</a> >>
        <a id="validate" href="javascript:void(0);">VALIDATE</a> >>
        <a id="organize" href="javascript:void(0);">ORGANIZE</a> >>
        <a id="export" href="javascript:void(0);">EXPORT</a>
    </p>
```

Attach click event using jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#import').on("click", function () {
                switchScreen('Import');
            });
            $('#validate').on("click", function () {
                switchScreen('Validate');
            });
            $('#organize').on("click", function () {
                switchScreen('Organize');
            });
            $('#export').on("click", function () {
                switchScreen('Export');
            });
});
```

Disable click event whenever required:

```
 $('#import').off('click');
 $('#validate').off('click');
 $('#organize').off('click');
 $('#export').off('click');
```

The above approach works for all standard browsers but just for IE we can have one more approach:

```
  $('#validate').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $('#organize').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $('#export').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: `disabled` doesn't apply to links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000927/should-the-html-anchor-tag-honor-the-disabled-attribute

Comment: `disabled` is a property -- in jQuery 1.7+ you should manipulate with `prop()`: e.g. `$('#validate').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 0):

You could have jQuery take over your inline event, so that you can `off()` it later. Note that `off()` **does** remove the listener. You can't really disable it unless you put some logic in the handler itself to bail out if it shouldn't be running.

```js
function switchScreen(screenName) {
  console.log(screenName);
};

$(function() {
  $('#menuitems a').each(function() {
    var oldClick = this.onclick;
    $(this).on('click', $.proxy(oldClick, this));
    this.onclick = null;
  });
  
  $('#import').off('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="menuitems" class="inline textcenter">
    <a id="import" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Import');">IMPORT</a> >> 
    <a id="validate" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Validate');">VALIDATE</a> >> 
    <a id="organize" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Organize');">ORGANIZE</a> >> 
    <a id="export" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="switchScreen('Export');">EXPORT</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try unbind instead of Off since click event is defined inline, if click is attached using on then it will work with off.

Comment: unbind is deprecated and not in use