# Disable onclick after click on <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a lot of table rows like:

```
<tr class="player" onclick="document.location = \'fight.php?fightplayer='.$rowselfight['name'].'\';">
```

All table rows have unique links. I now want to disable all the `onclick` links after one of them has been clicked on. I tried editing a piece of code I found somewhere else:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('onclick', '');
});
```

But it doesn't work, does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Just wondering, if you’re already using jQuery, then why are you still using this “old-school” way of event handling via HTML attributes anyway?

Comment: Like I said, I know nothing of jQuery or javascript, I simply looked up something that someone else posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `onclick` attribute on all the `tr`s instead of only the one being clicked:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    $("tr").attr('onclick', '');
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. Using it as:

    `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">$("tr").click(function() {
    $("tr").attr('onclick', '');
});</script>`

I'm trying to avoid people just spam clicking a link. It's for a game where you click a link to "fight". It already only fights once every 3 seconds, but you can just keep clicking and fight once every 3 seconds.

Comment: Could you also try with `$("tr").off('click');` instead of `$("tr").attr('onclick', '');` ?

Comment: It actually works, I'm so sorry! The link went to a page that was redirecting back to the page with this javascript on it. So every time it was clicked within 3 seconds it just redirected and could be clicked again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the removeAttr function?

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("onclick");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before. You want to remove the event handler from the HTML element. Please refer to: [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to remove the onclick from every other element, once the original has been clicked? Or have I misunderstood the question? Try:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    $("tr").attr('onclick', '');
});
```