# jQuery Unbind, Restore Bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of elements:

```
<a class="post-thumb" href="http://google.com">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
</a>

<a class="post-thumb" href="http://google.com">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
</a>

<a class="post-thumb" href="http://google.com">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
</a>
```

When a `.post-thumb` element is clicked it should add a class of `post-thumb--active` to itself and not fire the link, when the element is clicked again it should go to it's link as per normal. If the page is scrolled then all `.post-thumb` elements should go back to their original state.

The jQuery code I'm using at the minute is:

```
var $postThumb = $('.post-thumb'),
    $postThumbStoredClick;

$postThumb.on('click', function() {

  $(this).addClass('post-thumb--active');

  $postThumbStoredClick = $postThumb.data('events').click[0].handler;

  $(this).unbind('click');

  return false;

});

$(window).scroll(function() {

  $postThumb.removeClass('post-thumb--active');

  $postThumb.bind('click', $postThumbStoredClick);

});
```

This doesn't work 100%, for example if you click a `.post-thumb` element then click the one next to it then it fires the link, this shouldn't happen.

If anyone could help at all that'd be sweet as this is driving me crazy.

Comment: When I try your code, `$postThumb.data('events')` returns `undefined`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return from the click event handler if the element has the class `post-thumb--active`.

```
$postThumb.on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("post-thumb--active")) return;
    $(this).addClass('post-thumb--active');
    $postThumbStoredClick = $postThumb.data('events').click[0].handler;
    return false;
});
```

and change the window scroll handler to this...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $postThumb.removeClass('post-thumb--active');
});
```

That way, you're not having to remove and reassign the event handler based on anything else.

Comment: Perfect! I was overcomplicating it a lot, thanks for that. :)