# jQuery - How to remove the listeners to all from elements in single function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form, I have no.of form elements, I would like to remove all the listeners from the form elements.. how to achieve this?

here is my try, but not working..is this only way to remove each one by one?

```
    var testFunction = function () {
        $form = $('form'),
        $name = $form.find('#name'),
        $code = $form.find('#code'), //it will have more events..
        $city = $form.find('#city'), //it will have more events..
        $native = $form.find('#native'), //it will have more events..
        $gender = $form.find('#gender'), //it will have more events..
        $select = $form.find('#select'); //it will have more events..

//sample.

        $name.on('focus keydown input', function(e){
            console.log(e.target.value);
        });

        $select.on('change', function(e){
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    }

    testFunction();

    $('#unbindForm').on('click', function(){
        $('form').addClass('highlight').off(); //i can't remove all events?
    });
```

what would be the correct approach. in the `off` do i need to send all listeners what i used? (`change keydown input`)?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/Fv3PD/)

Comment: `$('form').addClass('highlight').off('focus keydown input');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the events from the elements just use `.off()` without passing any anrguments into it.

```
$('form *:not(#name)').off();
```

And here I have excluded the element with `id` name since you said that it does not have any events at all.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv3PD/3/)

Comment: I am trying to re-bind all events, I use your approach, it fails.. http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/Fv3PD/4/ can you look in to this?

Comment: @3gwebtrain This must be the well engineered solution for that http://jsfiddle.net/Fv3PD/6/

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv3PD/1/)**

Use **[.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)**  : With no arguments, `.unbind()` removes all handlers attached to the elements.

```
$('form *').unbind();
```

OR

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv3PD/2/)**

```
$('form *').off();
```

For **jQuery 1.7** > `.off()` is not available. Above 1.7, both the methods work. - **[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)**

Comment: I thought, even `off` will work so.. is it not? and it find each element right. is there any way to find listener alone and remove?