# jQuery remove click event handler from an element

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have this event handler,

```
$('#table_product').on 'click', '.th1',(event) ->
       $(this).unbind("click") #Not working
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user triggers this event, it will disable/detach the click event handler from `.th1`. So it won't give any response to the user for the next request.

Currently, I have tried `unbind()` and `off()`, but still no luck.. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: you can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) if you want event to fire only once .

Answer (score 0):

First, it could be useful if you give us more code, so we can test the code easily.

From the [API](http://api.jquery.com/click/) of jQuery:

```
$("#table_product").click(function() {

}
```

And from the answer of another question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery):

```
$('.th1').off('click');
```

Perhaps this will help?

Answer (score -1):

Try using "live" to bind the event and use "die" to unbind.

```
$('#table_product').live( "click", '.th1',(event)

$('#table_product').die( "click", foo );
```

Comment: `live` is dead as for jquery 1.9+