# Reset jquery .click functions on call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a kind of quiz script.
It's loading questions and keeping score but the "click" tag seems to be added with every new question. Instead of being changed. This leads to strange counting behavior which makes my script unusable. Is there someway that i can "reset" the click function? I've allready tried "overwriting" them but that doesn't seem to work.

```
var vragenArray = ["zero","Bla bla bla?","Boem Boem Boem?","Boing Boing Boing?","Floep Floep Floep?"];
var antA_Array = ["zero","antwoord1_a","antwoord2_a","antwoord3_a","antwoord4_a"];
var antB_Array = ["zero","antwoord1_b","antwoord2_b","antwoord3_b","antwoord4_b"];
var antC_Array = ["zero","antwoord1_c","antwoord2_c","antwoord3_c","antwoord4_c"];
var antD_Array = ["zero","antwoord1_d","antwoord2_d","antwoord3_d","antwoord4_d"];
var juistArray = ["zero","B","C","B","A"];
var aantalVragen = 21;
var counterVragen = 0;
var score = 0;
function laadVraag(){
    console.log("laadVraag geladen");
    counterVragen++;
    $("#vraagNummer").text(counterVragen);
    $("#vraag").text(vragenArray[counterVragen]);
    $("#antA").text(antA_Array[counterVragen]);
    $("#antB").text(antB_Array[counterVragen]);
    $("#antC").text(antC_Array[counterVragen]);
    $("#antD").text(antD_Array[counterVragen]);
    $("#score").text(score);
    $("#correct").text(juistArray[counterVragen]);
    $("#antA_click").click(function(){ laadVraag(); });
    $("#antB_click").click(function(){ laadVraag(); });
    $("#antC_click").click(function(){ laadVraag(); });
    $("#antD_click").click(function(){ laadVraag(); });
    juisteAntwoord(juistArray[counterVragen]);  
};
function juisteAntwoord(antwoord){
    console.log("juisteVraag geladen");
    $("#antB_click").click(function(){
        score++;
        laadVraag();
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    laadVraag();
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle with the current script.
http://jsfiddle.net/D7MMa/1/

Hope someone can help me out! :)

Answer (score 4):

I think a similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery), Basically what he is saying is that you can call unbind() to remove all click events

```
$('#elemendId').unbind('click');
```

but also that the API has been updated and .bind()/.unbind() are still available only for backwards compatibility purposes, and that you should use the off/on functions like so

```
$('#elemendId').click(function() { return false; }); // Adds another click event
$('#elemendId').off('click');
$('#elemendId').on('click.mynamespace', function() { /* Do stuff */ });
$('#elemendId').off('click.mynamespace');
```

You should read the post in the previous answer as he explains this in more detail. >Examples taken from the post above.

**Edit:** You can find the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RW3RE/2/) using the .unbind('click') method [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RW3RE/2/)
and with the [off()](http://jsfiddle.net/RW3RE/3/) method [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RW3RE/3/)

Comment: Can u please provide jsFiddle also ?

Comment: Done, both with .unbind() and .off() methods

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> Description: Remove an event handler.

*Code*

```
$(selector).off('click').on('click', function(){
    //Your Code
});
```

[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RW3RE/)