# In Javascript, how can I unbind a window event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
});
```

How can I unbind this?  I've tried .off, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: how did you tried using `.off()`?

Comment: `off` is correct so if it didn't work for you then you should include the code that you tried.

Comment: 25k rep - you should know better.  "Doesn't seem to work" is hardly a good description of a problem.

Comment: Also you have 1337 questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it on this website, but I assigned the callback to a separate variable

```
var callback = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}

$(window).on('scroll', callback);
```

and then to unset it

```
$(window).off('scroll', callback)
```

Comment: The OP is assigning a function expression (a so–called "anonymous function"), not a named function. How do you remove those?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it specifically for the handler.

```
scrollHandler = function() {
};

$(window).on('scroll', scrollHandler);
$(window).off('scroll', scrollHandler);
```