# How to remove exist custom 'click function' and replace new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble with ajax element, that when i add new element, i will inject new click function to that element, but he also add to the exist elements, so that some elements will call my function triple times or more.

So i wonder:

**How to remove exist custom 'click function' and replace new one?**

I know `.off()`but he remove all other functions of my elements so `hover()` still remove too.

Comment: Use event delegation, `$(staticParentSelector').on('click', 'dynamicChildSelector', function() {`

Comment: Next time when asking question, please add _complete_ and _relevant_ code. See [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: i'm sorry but i know `.on()`, but `.on()` `append new click` to `exist clicks`, that's not what i want.

Comment: Ok, add your code in question

Comment: in my view [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery) is good solution for your requirement:

Comment: Thanks **Mohammad Reza Rahimi** so much, now i can solve my problem.