# how to stop event by a condition

Tags: javascript

i've got this function and i need 'click' event to stop after input value reaches 0 and less

```
 function clickPlus(e) {
                  var parent = e.target.parentNode,
                      span = parent.querySelector('span'),
                      input = parent.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
                      inner = span.dataset.one,
                      price = inner * (++parent.querySelector('input').value);          
                      span.innerHTML = price; // price takes an input value
                      if (price > 10){
                         return false; // error here 
                      }         
                      countPrice();                  
                }
            for(i=0; i<pluses.length; i++) eventsObj.addEvent(pluses[i],'click', clickPlus);
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  The function will already stop and return false if price <= 0.

Comment: im checkin by console and it does. (condition works, if im puttin some msg about error) but 'click' still works(

Comment: If price <= 0 then `countPrice()` will not be called.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: countPrice(); is just another independant function, which are not ralated to this task
clickPlus works like a counter. And it shoul stop after reachin some value of input

Comment: After the line where you assign values to the vars, just check `input.value` and return if needed.

Answer (score -1):

The 'countPrice' function fires regardless of the if statement.

Try the other way round with your if statement or add an else...

```
if(price>0)
{
    countPrice();
}
```

Comment: No, the functions stops execution if price <= 0.

Answer (score -1):

Just unbind the click event from `pluses[i]`

You can unbind by calling the jquery unbind / off method.

```
$(pluses[i]).off('click');
```

value of `pluses[i]` is not given , so I am going to call the value as pluses[i] itself.

[For more info - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

[jquery off method](http://api.jquery.com/off/)