# How to run jquery countTo plugin when scrolling one once?

Tags: jquery

How to run jquery `countTo` plugin when scrolling one time?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $(".fact-to:in-viewport").countTo({
        speed: 500,
        refreshInterval: 2
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a flag:

```
var countFlag = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if(!countFlag) {
    countFlag = true;
    $(".fact-to:in-viewport").countTo({
      speed: 500,
      refreshInterval: 2
    });
  }
});
```

Or [unbind event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)