# bootstrap modal hide method - silent without event?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, events, modal-dialog, hide

I want to call `modal("hide")` in a 'silent' way - i.e. not to trigger the event handlers which I attached using `.on("hidden.bs.modal")`. How?

Comment: pls show us your code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a var isSilent inside your on hide event and have an if silent do nothing else do stuff, rather than trying to unbind events.

Answer (score 0):

I would unbind the event handler, hide the modal, and then re-bind the event handler. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/210345/4926817) for the best ways to remove an event handler.

The answer demonstrates using the jquery [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function like so:

```
$('#myimage').on('click.mynamespace', function() { /* Do stuff */ });
$('#myimage').off('click.mynamespace');
```

---

Alternative:

Temporarily override your trigger somewhere in your code, and then remove that piece of code when you are done:

`.on("hidden.bs.modal") {
   //do nothing
}`

Comment: Is there a better way? I prefer not to store my handlers in vars just to bind them again

Comment: @user3599803 I have updated my answer with an alternative, let me know if it helps.

Comment: you could put script tags in a `div` letting the id="script_div". then use jquery to append or remove the `div`