# unbind a click function after use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i a making a tic-tac-toe game and i now want to know how i can make a button unclickable after a click.
here is the game field:

```
<div id="gamefield">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img alt="" title="" src="img/empty.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

this is the randomstart function:

```
var randomStart = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
```

this is the function for the gamefield:

```
$("#gamefieldtr td").click(function() {
    if ($(".game-button").html() == "Start spel") {
        alert("you can't start");
    } else {
        if(randomStart == 0){
            var val = $(this).children().attr('src', 'img/cross.jpg');
            randomStart = 1;
            $("#playerTurn").html("1");
            $("#turnImg").attr("src", "img/circle.jpg");
        }
        else {
            var val = $(this).children().attr('src', 'img/circle.jpg');
            randomStart = 0;
            $("#playerTurn").html("0");
            $("#turnImg").attr("src", "img/cross.jpg");
            $('src', 'img/circle.jpg').unbind("click");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Comment: Mark the button as clicked with a class and return false on the event handler when the button has said class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use jquery's [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of click() to add the event handlers:

> **.one( events [, data ], handler ) Returns: jQuery**
>
> **Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.
>
> version added: 1.1.one( events [, data ], handler )

Here's how the code should look like:

```
$('#gamefieldtr td').one('click', function (event) {
  // your logic here
})
```

Handlers added with one() are automatically removed once they've been triggered, so you don't have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unbind an event there is the function [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) in jquery

> **.off()**
>
> .off( events [, selector ] [, handler ] )
>
> **Description:**
> Remove an event handler.

```
$("#gamefieldtr td").click(function() {

    // PUT THE LINE BELOW WHERE YOU WANT TO UNBIND YOUR CLICK EVENT OF YOUR TR
    $("td").off("click", "#gamefieldtr");

    if ($(".game-button").html() == "Start spel") {
        alert("you can't start");
    } else {
        if(randomStart == 0){
            var val = $(this).children().attr('src', 'img/cross.jpg');
            randomStart = 1;
            $("#playerTurn").html("1");
            $("#turnImg").attr("src", "img/circle.jpg");
        }
        else {
            var val = $(this).children().attr('src', 'img/circle.jpg');
            randomStart = 0;
            $("#playerTurn").html("0");
            $("#turnImg").attr("src", "img/cross.jpg");
            $('src', 'img/circle.jpg').unbind("click");
        }
    }
});
```