# Removing click events

Tags: jquery, event-handling, click

I'm currently making a Match Two app (tap on squares, find the matching pictures)
I am having issues with 1 part of it. Disabling the click event so a certain square can't be clicked until it resets itself. I've tried replaceWith but the issue with that is that once I run that the event doesn't run again even if I use attr to put the id back in. I've tried off() but that just seems to break it.

HTML Snippet:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td id="" colspan="3">Lifes Remaining:</td>
            <td id="lives"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="1to4">
            <td class="a1" id="a1">0</td>
            <td class="a2" id="a2">0</td>
            <td class="a3" id="a3">0</td>
            <td class="a4" id="a4">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input type="button" id="press" value="Press" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Code Snippet:

```
var set1a = 1, set1b = 1, set2a = 2, set2b = 2;

var rand1 = 0;
var rand2 = 0;

var lives;
var savedData1 = "", savedData2 = "";
var check1 = "", check2 = "";
var idCheck1 = "", idCheck2 = "";
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#lives").text("");
    $("#press").click(function()
    {
        lives = 3;  
        $("#lives").text(lives);

        for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {$("#a"+i).text("0").css('color', 'black');}
        i = 0;
<!-----------------Set Position--------------------------------->               
        do{rand1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);}
        while($("#a"+rand1).text() != 0)
        $("#a"+rand1).text(set1a);

        do{rand2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);}
        while($("#a"+rand2).text() != 0)
        $("#a"+rand2).text(set1b);

        do{rand1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);}
        while($("#a"+rand1).text() != 0)
        $("#a"+rand1).text(set2a);

        do{rand2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);}
        while($("#a"+rand2).text() != 0)
        $("#a"+rand2).text(set2b);
<!-----------------Set Position--------------------------------->                       
    });
        $("#a1").click(function()
        {
            $(".a1").css('color', 'lightgreen');

            if(check1 == "")
                check1 = $("#a1").text();
            else
                check2 = $("#a1").text();

            if(idCheck1 == "")
                idCheck1 = "#a1";
            else
                idCheck2 = "#a1"

            if(check1 && check2 != "")
            {
                if(check1 != check2)
                {
                    $(".a1").css('color', 'black');
                }
            }
        });

        $("#a2").click(function()
        {
            $(".a1").css('color', 'lightgreen');
            check1 = '1';
            if(idCheck1 == "")
            {
                idCheck1 = "#a1";
            }
            else
               idCheck2 = "#a1"

            if(check1 && check2 != "")
            {
                $(".a1").css('color', 'black');
            }
        }); 

        $("#a3").click(function()
        {

        }); 

        $("#a4").click(function()
        {

        });     
    });
```

I need something to use in the #a1-4 click functions that allow me to disable the click function of the number that is tapped until another number is tapped and then re enable it.

Something like

```
$("#a1").click(function()
    {
        if(check1 == "")
            check1 = $("#a1").text();
        else
            check2 = $("#a1").text();

        if(idCheck1 == "")
            idCheck1 = "#a1";
        else
            idCheck2 = "#a1"

        *Disable #a1 click function*    
        if(check1 && check2 != "")
        {
            if(check1 != check2)
            {
                $(".a1").css('color', 'black');
                *Enable #a1 click function*
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help would be appricated and if you need any clarification, let me know

Mike

Comment: have you tried unbind and bind 
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/
http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 1):

`$('#a1').unbind('click')` will remove the click event listener.

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/210345/5758328

Comment: unbind worked thanks. even though I was sure I had tried it. How to do bind it again? I see in the stack overflow answer you linked me, it's more of a function than just straight code

Comment: .bind() or .click again or .on look at the SO answer i linked to.