# Javascript disable double click on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an issue about embedded canvas is that I don't want
to use double click feature on it.

While API given by Sketchfab doesn't offer such functionality, is there a way to block event getting there in the first place ?

UPDATE:

I am embedding model from Sketchfab.

Here's the embed:

```
<div class="sketchfab-embed-wrapper"><iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/9eb60eebc20e45c4b586e1a6fe6c5983/embed" frameborder="0" allowvr allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" onmousewheel=""></iframe>
...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @hindmost Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated that you are using Sketchfab (which is embedded with an iframe) this is not possible due to XSS protection. No major browser will allow you to access embedded cross site content.

Take a look at this link for more information about [cross-frame scripting and security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

can you check this? [Remove Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

```
$('canvas').off('dblclick');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtbypwLb/

Comment: I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).off is not a function`

Comment: I added jsfiddle link. Check this. maybe you didnt add jquery to your page.