# Removed onmouseover but can't bring back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys simple problem I think. Have 3 divs, trying to remove and add back OnMouseOver for "body_flex" div.  What am I missing here?

```
function contact_open() {
        $("#body_flex_wrapper_id").removeAttr('onmouseover')
}
function contact_close() {
        $("#body_flex_wrapper_id").attr('onmouseover');     
}
```

Comment: use `.bind()` and `.unbind()`

Comment: I think your best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Comment: Keep in mind that `.bind()` and `.unbind()` have been depreciated. Use `.on()` and .`off()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/bind/ and http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ @guradio

Answer (score 1):

you can toggle that using `attr` and `removeAttr`

```js
$(function(){
  $("#btnToggle").click(function(){
     if ($("#div1").attr("onmouseover")){
          $("#div1").removeAttr("onmouseover");
     }
     else{
        $("#div1").attr("onmouseover", "overx();");
     }
  })

})

function overx(e){
   console.log($("#div1").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnToggle">Toggle</button>

<div id="div1" onmouseover="overx();">
  <span>sample div</span>
</div>
```

Comment: please mark it as an answer if this answer is what you're looking for so we could have a better reference in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function contact_open() {
    $("#body_flex_wrapper_id").removeProp('onmouseover', null);
}
function contact_close() {
        $("#body_flex_wrapper_id").prop('onmouseover', null);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `.bind()` and `.unbind()` have been depreciated. Use `.on()` and .`off()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/bind/ and http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: same for .on and .off

Comment: removeProp does its job, but prop won't bring it back.  What about disabling a function?  The mouseover is just on a large div that slides a menu back when user rolls over.  So if we can't disable the mouseover on it, what about the function that MO is calling?