# jQuery still invoking previous page functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

we Load our pages from the menu link using ajax (clear main div and then load url of clicked menu)

the issue we are facing is that jQuery still calls the functions which were in previous page and should not be invoked for next page ..

an example jquery code is as under:

```
 $("#ComponentContainer").load(url, function (response, status, xhr) {

        if (response != null && response.Code != undefined && response.Code == 502) {
            ShowAlertMessage(response.ResponseText, response.MessageClass);
        }

        if (typeof PostPageLoad == 'function') {
            PostPageLoad();
        }
        //$("#ComponentHeading").html(title);
        if (typeof SelectNoteRows === "function") {
            SelectNoteRows();
        }
    });
```

e.g. the function `SelectNoteRows` was present on page A and should work as needed . but it is still being invoked when loading page B via ajax which is causing unrequired behaviour

any help appreciated..

Comment: Thats because when you replace the content of main div, it only replaces the html and not the script with it...

Comment: What you need to do is to save state (page your in) in some variable and check that page in load function and call different function on each page.

Comment: @Simple_Programmer the script is dynamically added inside the main div . so shouldnt it also be removed when contents of main div are cleared (using $("#id").empty(); to remove the content) ?

Comment: The functions are not removed when you call `empty()` they are in browser memory

Comment: any way to remove them ;(

Comment: `SelectNoteRows = undefined;`

Comment: If the script tag containing the scripts is part of the content dynamically loaded in that div then it will be removed on call of `empty()`

Comment: @Simple_Programmer yes they are actually inside the pages which are being loaded in the main div via ajax

Comment: or `SelectNoteRows = null;` -> `(typeof SelectNoteRows === "function") == false`

Comment: search for binding methods and unbinding ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)