# Can I unbind an "on" update function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bind, unbind

Is it possible to unbind a .on "update" function?

**Example:**

```
price_slider_element.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {

      // Code
});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to unbind all the handlers for the event you can use `off('event')` however that will remove all the event handlers for that event.

If you want to remove a specific one, you would want to make the callback a named function, or stored in a variable, and then use `off('event', methodName)` and then only that particular handler will be removed.

```
function thing () {}

$(selector).on('click', thing);
//removes all click event handlers
$(selector).off('click');
//removes just one
$(selector).off('click', thing);
```

Comment: Is it possible to have syntax similar to $(element).unbind("click").bind("click") ?

Comment: unbind (and bind) has been deprecated, and most likely is just a wrapper around off, so yes you should be able to chain like that I would believe.