# jQuery Ajax - Load function duplicates click event handlers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, duplicates

I have a problem with jQuery Ajax. I have a load function:

- main file which load a first page to #my_div
- ajax.php file to load next or prev page to #my_div.

I will add that this is a very simplified pattern, I ultimately have many functions and things. I present a basic problem here.

Main file:

```
<div>
    <div id="my_div"></div>
    <button id="prevstep">back</button>
    <button id="nextstep">next</button>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery("#my_div").load("http://localhost/ajax.php?section=page1");
</script>
```

ajax.php file:

```
<?php
if ($_GET["section"] == "page1") {
    ?>
    <div>something part 1</div>
    <script>
        $("#prevstep").on("click", function() {
            console.log("test1 back");
            jQuery("#my_div").load("http://localhost/ajax.php?section=page0");
        });
        $("#nextstep").on("click", function() {
            console.log("test1 next");
            jQuery("#my_div").load("http://localhost/ajax.php?section=page2");
        });
    </script>
    <?php
} elseif ($_GET["section"] == "page2") {
    ?>
    <div>something part 2</div>
    <script>
        $("#prevstep").on("click", function() {
            console.log("test2 back");
            jQuery("#my_div").load("http://localhost/ajax.php?section=page0");
        });
        $("#nextstep").on("click", function() {
            console.log("test2 next");
            jQuery("#my_div").load("http://localhost/ajax.php?section=page2");
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Site working correctly (jquery library is correct, console doesn't return any errors), but when I switch between page1 and page2 - console return strange values after loading again the same page.

For example:

1. Load main file, console nothing return - ok
2. Click 'next' button, console return:

test1 next

3. Click 'back' button (to back from page2 to page1), console return:

test1 back

test2 back

4. Click again 'next' button (to go to page2), console return:

test1 next

test2 next

5. Click again 'back' button (to back to page1), console return:

test1 back

test2 back

test2 back

test2 back

6. Third time I click 'next' button, console return:

test1 next

test2 next

test2 next

test2 next

7. Third time I click 'back' button, console return:

test1 back

test2 back

test2 back

test2 back

test2 back

test2 back

test2 back

test2 back

Scripts duplicate each time the next page loads again.

How to resolve this problem?

BTW. I using a jQuery v2.2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must move your scripts to the "Main file".

On every page change, your scripts from PHP file, are loading and executing over and over again and they are adding extra "click events" every time.

**Update:**
Also, you can unbind click event handlers in PHP files.
Add this line of code to your scripts in PHP file:

```
$('#myimage').unbind('click'); //jquery <1.7
```

or

```
$('#myimage').off('click'); //jquery >3.0
```

For example:

```
<script>
    $('#nextstep').unbind('click');
    $('#prevstep').unbind('click');        
    $("#prevstep").on("click", function() {
        console.log("te.......
```

[Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

Comment: I can't move scripts to "main file" because some scripts (which are not included here and also double when loading) they have variable content generated by the php code and it would be difficult to extract all this using javascript to the main file. After that, I have about 10 pages, and each has different tasks.

Comment: I need to resolve my problem without moving scripts to main file. Scripts must be in ajax.php file.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your explanation. You only need to unbind click events on every ajax call.

Comment: @WooQash `.unbind` is deprecated in 3.0

Comment: make use of $('#id').off('click'); if you are using jquery 3+ @WooQash

Comment: @WooQash so... you are attaching and detaching events across 10 different pages ? O_o

Answer (score 0):

Your events are still bound when replacing content. Since your navigation buttons don't change you keep on adding handlers to them. Check events bound to your elements in the browser's inspector. And take a look on how to turn [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) handlers.

Or you could find an alternative way to keep track of the current / previous / next pages without reattaching handlers and avoid the problem entirely, as demonstrated in the next example.

This will keep track of current page by itself (be sure to update the number of pages in `nextstep` handler):

```
(function() {
  var page = 1;

  $("#my_div").load("http://localhost/ajax.php?section=page1");

  $('#prevstep').click(function() {
    if (page > 1) {
      page = page - 1;
      load();
    }
  });

  $('#nextstep').click(function() {
    // Check your bounds
    page = page + 1;
    load();
  });

  function load() {
    $('#my_div').load("http://localhost/ajax.php?section=page" + page);
  }
})();
```

Allowing your sample php to be reduced to:

```
if ($_GET["section"] == "page1") {
    ?>
    <div>something part 1</div>
    <?php
} elseif ($_GET["section"] == "page2") {
    ?>
    <div>something part 2</div>
    <?php
}
```

But if your sample php is trimmed down, this might not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem like you. In my case, i have static navbar and sidebar (contain many menu and sub menu), and the content is dynamically load by ajax. The problem appear when i navigate to another page, the old event from old page still in jquery event listener and make duplicate event trigger.

This is an example how i bind an event to every dynamic element inside the content.

```
$("#content").on("click",'#add-btn', addButtonHandler)
```

So before i get the HTML and script from another page to i store inside the content. I must unbind all event so the duplicate event not appear. This is the code:

```
$('#content').off('', '')
```

After that i can store the data to #content element :).

FUll code example how i get data from another page and remove all event:

```
$.ajax('http://localhost/test_ajax_content/p.html', {
      success: function (data) {
                  $('#content').off('', '')
                  $("#content").html(data)
              }
})
```