# How to make an element with specific class ignore a global listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a global listener on specific input type:

```
$('input[type["radio"]').on('change', function() { ... });
```

But I have another more specific `radio` input with its own `unique_radio` class:

```
<input type="radio" class="unique_radio" name="unique_radio">
```

It also has its own click listener:

```
$('.unique_radio').on('click', function() { ... });
```

When I click it, both listeners trigger the functions, but I need only the function with the unique_radio listener to be triggered.

I have tried using `stopImmediatePropagation` and `off` as seen here:

[Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

But that did not seem to work

Comment: who marked it as duplicate? it's the marked post does not work, it's two different type of listeners

Comment: `evt.stopXXX` only apply to the current event *type* - it looks like you have a change and a click - which are not the same event types.  Please provide some HTML so a solution can be provided.   It looks like you could *cancel* the click event then change the value manually (via code) which won't raise the change event.

Comment: It was likely closed as you mentioned `stopImmediatePropagation` which stops the *same* event type and stops it going to the parent - you don't appear to have a hierarchy scenario, but without HTML, it's not 100% clear.  Please provide relevant HTML to *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: The way to handle something like this is to simply make the global listener ignore the element with the specific class. It is a simple `if ()` statement

Comment: ... as in.. `$('input[type["radio"]').on('change', function(e) { if ($(e.target).hasClass('.unique_radio') { return } else { ... }  });`

Comment: @slebetman in which case you might as well exclude it from the listener: `$('input[type["radio"]:not(.unique_radio)').on('change',`

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not working with my jquery but you can see below my sample so you can use it directly. You can use this to ignore input with unique_radio class. Use :not() [explain](https://api.jquery.com/not/) with this you dont have to use preventDefault or return false.

My code;

```
$('input[type="radio"]:not(.unique_radio)').on('change', function(){
    console.log(1);
});
$('.unique_radio').on('change', function() {
    console.log(2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is if you attach event listener to all radio

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() { 
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>First</label>
  <input type="radio" name="unique_radio" data-id="first">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Second</label>
  <input type="radio" name="unique_radio"  data-id="second">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Third</label>
  <input type="radio" class="unique_radio" name="unique_radio"  data-id="third">
</div>
```

If you want to remove listener on one radio with a particular class you can do it in different way

Here you restrict the execution only for radios which hasn't class `unique_radio`

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() { 
    let $target = $(this);
    if(!$target.hasClass('unique_radio')) {
       console.log($target.data('id'));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>First</label>
  <input type="radio" name="unique_radio" data-id="first">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Second</label>
  <input type="radio" name="unique_radio"  data-id="second">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Third</label>
  <input type="radio" class="unique_radio" name="unique_radio"  data-id="third">
</div>
```

Here if you want to remove the handler

```js
let handler = function() { 
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
}

$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', handler);
$('.unique_radio').unbind('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>First</label>
  <input type="radio" name="unique_radio" data-id="first">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Second</label>
  <input type="radio" name="unique_radio"  data-id="second">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Third</label>
  <input type="radio" class="unique_radio" name="unique_radio"  data-id="third">
</div>
```